How to get all loaded classes during the response generation?
I've used autoload but it's not giving all the files/classes that's been used during request
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $logFile = __DIR__ . '/autoload_log.txt';
    $message = $class . "\n";
    file_put_contents($logFile, $message, FILE_APPEND);
}, true, true);

Is there any other way to trace all classes that's been involved during the page generation for Symfony project?

"it's not giving all the files/classes" - did you see any common parts between the classes that were used, and those that were missing? Like: only your own classes get recorded, but those from the vendor folder were not?

Not all of the own classes are recorded, that's the case.

Did you check whether they were already autoloaded before the new handler was added?

Yes, new handler is added before all others

Getting declared classes was the only valuable solution:
$loadedClasses = get_declared_classes();
sort($loadedClasses);
$logFile = __DIR__ . '/autoload_log_declared.txt';
$logContent = implode("\n", $loadedClasses);
file_put_contents($logFile, $logContent, FILE_APPEND);

